# AddLiquidityETH in contract constructor failing after RouterV2 calls V2pair mint function

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, uniswap

I have been trying to integrate a liquidity add into the constructor for my ERC20 token. The relevant code is as follows:

```
interface Router02 {
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
}

contract TestToken is BEP20('Test Token', 'Test') {
    constructor() public payable  {
    uint  tokenAmount = 1000000000000000000000000000000;
    uint  ethAmount = 100000000000000000;
    require(msg.value == ethAmount);
     _mint(address(this),tokenAmount);
 _approve(address(this), Router02addr, tokenAmount);
 BEP20(0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab).approve(Router02addr,100000000000000000);
        Router02(Router02addr).addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, 
            0, 
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );
}'
```

The majority of the calls in the transaction execute without error, according to the stack trace:
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/ropsten/0x8462db9b535c3cf6cb6b585592cbb1c10522f0dbc12f449d25d2baafc65866f6

However, at the final stage of the transaction, when the RouterV2 contract calls the pair contract to mint tokens to the specified address, it reverts for some reason and doesn't indicate why. I believe I have all the approvals set up correctly, and I can't see any reason why the transaction would revert. If anyone could give me more insight on this I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Owner is not set on constructor

Comment: Appears to be minting LP tokens to the correct address according to the debug trace. Same issue also occurred when owner() was swapped for address(this)
`"value":"0"
"[INPUT]":"0x6a62784200000000000000000000000090f196caa356b39f055fb68572bb5a09e7038aaa"
"[OUTPUT]":"0x"
"[ERROR]":"execution reverted"
"local_variables":{
"pair":"0x4252625ea65001a3b39f040742aba26a9656357e"
}`